# how to write a class that has array of anything as member

Tags: scala

I'm trying to find a way to write the following code elegantly with scala :

```
case class Foo(type: String, value: Array[Byte])
```

The value member holds an array that can be of different type. For example if `type = "Double"`
it should store an `Array[Double]` and for `type = "Float"` it should store an `Array[Float]` and so on. Currently, I convert my Array[T] into Array[Byte] but it's not very convenient. Is it possible to have a parameter for my case class and just set the value with the concrete type

```
value: Array[Type] = some: Array[ConcreteType]
```

Best

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to express exactly what you want in Scala type system, because it would require [dependent types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_types). You can, however, do something very similar:

```
case class Foo[T: ClassTag](innerArray: Array[T]) {
  val classTag = implicitly[ClassTag[T]]
}
```

That way you will be able to do something like this:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

    case class Foo[T: ClassTag](innerArray: Array[T]) {
      val classTag = implicitly[ClassTag[T]]
    }

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class Foo

scala> Foo(Array[Int](1, 2, 3))
res0: Foo[Int] = Foo([I@17160134)

scala> res0.classTag.runtimeClass.getSimpleName
res1: String = int
```

See how Scala automatically provides a `ClassTag` for you. Using that `ClassTag` you will be able to recover class name, and, moreover, Scala will force that `ClassTag` corresponds exactly to `T` and not to some other type.

Comment: Thanks, it corresponds to what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use type parameters in case class definition:

```
    case class Foo[T](typeName: String, innerArray: Array[T])

    val intArray: Array[Int] = Array(1,2,3)
    val foo = Foo("foo", intArray)

    val stringArray: Array[String] = Array("a", "b", "c")
    val bar = Foo("bar", stringArray)
```